# Set UIStackView axis according to the screen size

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am creating a `UIStackView` containing text fields, I want the `UIStackView`'s axis to be horizontal on all screens except the iPhone 5s, I want the `UIStackView`'s axis to be vertical.

Is this possible?
If yes, How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if the device is iPhone 5.

```
 func isIPhone5 () -> Bool {
    return max(UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.height) == 568.0
}
```

If this function returns true, the device is iPhone 5. So with reference of stackView, you can change the axis of UIStackView.

```
if isIPhone5() {
            stackView.axis = .vertical
   }
```